# Does this sentence "it doesn't meet the blind's need who want to read." make sense?

Tags: grammaticality, pronouns, relative-clauses

Does the following sentence make sense grammatically or practically? Can I use it as it is without any correlation?

"it doesn't meet the blind's need who want to read."

Comment: The sentence is *grammatical*. But as it stands, without any further context, it is ambiguous.

Comment: It doesn't meet the need of the blind, who also want to read.

Comment: @JasonBassford, ambiguous how?

Comment: @Toothrot There was some previous discussion about the possible meanings but those comments have been deleted. ("Wrong sort of comments" for the elitists who manage this place, presumably.) It isn't clear what the needs of the blind are. Are they the desire to read? Are they unrelated to reading? But in that case, why introduce reading?

Comment: @Toothrot It doesn't state what the need of the blind *is*. Some comments I'd given have been deleted. Do they need food? Clothing? Or is it describing their need to read? The sentence, as written, doesn't explicitly specify.

Comment: @JasonBassford, oh, I see.  I wouldn't say that makes it _ambiguous_ though. ... I assumed the need was simply the need to read.

Comment: That's exactly *why* it's ambiguous. You're making an assumption. Other people could make different assumptions.

Comment: @JasonBassford, what I mean is that, when you say it is ambiguous, it sounds as if it's grammatically ambiguous; but what you meant was merely that we do not know what specific need 'need' refers to.  this is like saying that 'a man is lurking in the bushes' is ambiguous because we do not know whether he young or old.

Comment: @Toothrot It's the *syntax* that is being used in such a way that it's not clear how the sentence should be parsed. (1) For those blind who want to read, it doesn't meet that need. (2) It doesn't meet a particular need of those blind who also happen to want to read. The wording of the sentence means that either one of these interpretations *could* be correct. The fact that it's not clear *which* of those two is correct is what makes it ambiguous.

Comment: @JasonBassford, all right, you have a point.

Answer (score 3):

The example sentence

> - **It doesn't meet the blind's need who want to read.*

is ungrammatical (that's what the asterisk indicates), because the relative clause *who want to read* has as antecedent the noun phrase *the blind*, but it follows a different noun, *need*, which is the head of the noun phrase *the blind's need*. So the relative clause, which ought to immediately follow its antecedent, is not in the right place to be understood correctly. That's what makes it ungrammatical.

And moving it around won't help. *The blind* is actually inflected with the possessive clitic *-'s*, so you can't put the relative clause right after it with impunity:

- ?*It doesn't meet the blind who want to read's need.*

If you want to use a relative clause, put its antecedent right before it:

- *It doesn't meet the need of the blind who want to read.*

This has the unfortunate property of rhyming, but that can be fixed.

Comment: Yeah, on second thought I'd award it only a ?. I'll change the stigma.

Comment: Is your claim that this has always been ungrammatical in modern English,
or that it has at some point (which?) become ungrammatical?

Comment: No, I have no idea what the history of the construction is. That's a totally different question. Most Modern English syntax is novel, since we've lost most of the morphology that other languages can use instead. And there's a lot of syntax, most of which was never written down because it was spoken by illiterate people and not printed.

Comment: Allow me a more precise question: are you open to the possibility that
this construction was used in 20th-century (or 19th-century) literature
and was therefore, at some point in the 20th (or 19th) century, not
ungrammatical?

Comment: Being grammatical is a personal matter. People's habits and understandings change as they gain more experience, and since lives vary, so do judgements on grammaticality. To say it was grammatical at some past time is to summarize all the personal judgements of speakers at some past time. No doubt it was for some and not for others.

Comment: All right; but, if your notion of grammaticality is _that_
subjectivistic, you seem to me at least to be undermining your own
answer.

Comment: The problem is in thinking that "grammatical" is a solid yes-or-no concept, when it's just the froth on the ocean of speech. Think about how many words a speaker says every day, and multiply by the number of days in three generations and by the number of English speakers. And we can't ask the folks back then how they felt about syntax because syntax and sociolinguistics only go back to the late 20th century. That gives some idea of how far the English of 1919 is from the English of 2019.

Answer (score -3):

After looking at the sentence again, I think the problem with it is the word „blind“ appears in the singular and English doesn‘t use the word „blind“, as in „the blind“ or „a blind“ to refer to just one blind individual. You can say „a blind person“, or a „blind individual“ or you can use the word in its plural and say, „the blind“ in the general sense, but those are the only options. So, if you were referring to the blind in general (as a group), your sentence should look more like this, „it doesn‘t meet the needs of the blind who want to read.“

Comment: The -'s possessive can be used with plural words that aren't pluralized with -s.

Comment: Please edit all your posts that have the wrong sort of quotation marks so that they are correct in written English.

Comment: @tchrist, quotation marks are a matter of style, not correct English.

Comment: @Toothrot Only partly. The choice between single/double quotes is a matter of style; what form of quotes to use is a matter of language. German-style quote marks like the ones used here are not considered correct punctuation in English, just like using “;” to mark questions or “¿” to introduce them would not be.

Comment: Related to the quotation discussion: https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12097/49890

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, I would still call ; and ¿ excentric typography
rather than incorrect English, and „ “ excentric but much less
excentric.  Frankly I think this is unimportant.  It's not as if this
site has any real typography anyway (most posts don't even have correct
grammar); most quotation marks are " ", which corresponds to the
non-typography of typewriters and is inferior to German marks even in
English.  To elevate what printers happen to have been doing to a
requirement of correct language is silly.